# How to put a glyphicon in a simple_form submit in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, simple-form, glyphicons

I wanted to edit my simple_form submit button, replacing the label by a glyphicon but couldn't do it.

Is there a nice way to perform this trick ?

Many thanks !

**EDIT:**

Haml code with working button :

```
= link_to [:admin, comment], method: :delete, data:{confirm: "are you sure ?"}, class: "btn btn-sm btn-danger" do
  %i.glyphicon.glyphicon-trash
```

But it does't work with a submit button...

Comment: `sublime_form` - are you sure?

Comment: There is no files, add at least your html

Comment: Fixed the typo, my bad. Added HAML working code for example too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good way to do it was to simply put a `button` input instead of a simple `submit` one, since a button in a from submits it.

```
= f.button :submit do
  %i.glyphicon.glyphicon-user
  Add user
```

It actually works.

It seems that simple_form is more strict on the form submit's code structure.

Answer (score 1):

for rails 4.2+ and 'simple_form (~> 3.1.0) what worked for me was changing

```
<%= f.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-success' %>
```

to

```
<%= f.button :button, class: 'btn btn-success' do %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true></span> Update Form
    <% end %>
```

by changing

1. the :submit to a :button
2. adding a span to introduction the glyphicon
3. add the text label, which was auto generated but now I need to supply it if I want any text

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me!